# Create a new port for Macports

Tags: macports

I hate to wait for Macports to update the packages that I need. I would like to learn how to create a new port and submit it to Macports server. How do I do that?

Comment: Did you have a look at https://trac.macports.org/?

Comment: I was actually looking for a quick tutorial, the guide given on the MacPorts website is so lengthy.. I hope somebody had done such task can just give me a how-to brief.

Answer (score 4):

An easier way probably does not exists "they would have it listed on the site if there was a fast track" you are going to have to read and understand many of the things listed under [MacPorts Development](https://trac.macports.org/#MacPortsDevelopment). It is a complicated system, you have to take the time to understand how it works, and what the rules and guidelines are for using and working with it.

I am not currently a MacPorts developer but you could try asking / searching the archives for your question on [MacPorts Mailing list](http://www.macports.org/contact.php#Lists), but I suspect if you do ask this question they are going to tell you the same thing I just did above. Either way if you want to get started developing ports for MacPorts getting started and having access to that Mailing list resource will help you go a long way.